# Sql HierarchyId How do I get the 2 level ancestors

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

Using sql hierarchy Id how do I get all of the rows that have no children (that is the last decendants)?

Say my table is structured like this:

```
 Id, 
 Name,
 HierarchyId
```

And has these rows:

```
1, Craig, /
2, Steve, /1/
3, John, /1/1/
4, Collin /1/1/1
5, Sam, /2/
6, Matt, /2/1/
7, Chris, /2/1/1/
8, Molly, /2/1/1/1
```

Now when I pass the Id = 8, i.e. for molly i want ancestors 2 levels up that means Matt and chris

similarly for others also.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify following query to achieve this:

```
declare @hierarchyid hierarchyid
select @hierarchyid = [HierarchyId] from table_name where id = child_id
select * from table_name where [HierarchyId] in (@hierarchyid.GetAncestor(2))
```